# Flutter: How to add marker to Google Maps with new Marker API?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

```
    mapController.addMarker(
  MarkerOptions(
    position: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
  ),
);
```

I've seen this code snippet in a [blog post](https://medium.com/flutter-community/exploring-google-maps-in-flutter-8a86d3783d24), and I'm trying to add markers to Google Maps.

> The method 'addMarker' isn't defined for the class 'GoogleMapController'.

I think the library has changed and I want to know what's the new way doing this, I've looked up in the [controller.dart](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/controller.dart) and [api reference](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/) but couldn't figure it out.

I would be happy to see some tutorials and blog posts about it, don't hesitate to share.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, The google maps API has changed and the Marker API is widget based and not based in controller anymore.

By [CHANGELOG.md](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter#030)

*"Breaking change. Changed the Marker API to be widget based, it was controller based. Also changed the example app to account for the same."*

I copy some pieces of code from [github app example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart) that I think is important to you

```
Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{}; // CLASS MEMBER, MAP OF MARKS

void _add() {
    var markerIdVal = MyWayToGenerateId();
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);

    // creating a new MARKER
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(
        center.latitude + sin(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
        center.longitude + cos(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
      ),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: markerIdVal, snippet: '*'),
      onTap: () {
        _onMarkerTapped(markerId);
      },
    );

    setState(() {
      // adding a new marker to map
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
}

GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
                zoom: 11.0,
              ),
              // TODO(iskakaushik): Remove this when collection literals makes it to stable.
              // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28312
              // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values), // YOUR MARKS IN MAP
)
```

I advise you take a look in example app [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart). There is updated to new API.

Comment: These links have been moved to https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart

Comment: Thanks a lot @A.S.H

Comment: Where do you call _add()? What if I want to frill my markers list in initState?

Comment: I want to add marker in flutter map web

Answer (score 6):

I did below example from google [codelabs.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter#4)

```
Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
LatLng _center =  LatLng(9.669111, 80.014007);
```

onMap created add single static marker

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;

    final marker = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('place_name'),
      position: LatLng(9.669111, 80.014007),
      // icon: BitmapDescriptor.,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(
        title: 'title',
        snippet: 'address',
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      markers[MarkerId('place_name')] = marker;
    });
  }
```

google map widget:

```
GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 14.0,
                ),
                markers: markers.values.toSet(),
              ),
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's your solution.

So, this is the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://www.veed.io/view/2caa75f2-fcb5-4aff-8150-8aac8dae5cdc?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Source code:

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  bool visibility = false;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(visibility ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
        onPressed: () {
          visibility = !visibility;
          _add();
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
          markers: markers.values.toSet(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _add() {
    const marker1 = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('place_name1'),
      position: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    );
    const marker2 = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('place_name2'),
      position: LatLng(37.422131, -122.084801),
    );
    if (visibility) {
      markers[const MarkerId('place_name1')] = marker1;
      markers[const MarkerId('place_name2')] = marker2;
    } else {
      var blankMarker = const Marker(markerId: MarkerId(""));
      markers[const MarkerId('place_name1')] = blankMarker;
      markers[const MarkerId('place_name2')] = blankMarker;
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: How it is different than the accepted answer? Do you mind explaining the code instead of sending video?

Comment: In _add() function, you can see the condition. So, when there's visibility on that time, we're assigning the actual values to the markers and in the else part, we're de-assigning the actual values, or I can say we're re-assigning it with fake values.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It sounds like you are toggling markers by replacing with blank ones but I think it's not related to the question or solve anything. This question is solved when users point me out changelog and new way to add markers, 4 years ago.