# How to use flutter_google_places_autocomplete in flutter using it's latest version?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am very new to Flutter, don't know how to implement it. An example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example [blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-places-location-search-with-map-view-using-flutter-1-0-alfian-losari-66cacb3bcc24) post by Alfian Losari on Medium.com. Easy to find that blog post if you search 'flutter google maps places' on google by the way.

And I suggest that you take a look at official google maps plugins [changelog](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/CHANGELOG.md#030). Because the example in that blog post using old marker api, where you have to add your markers on GoogleMapsController. So if you want to update the plugin, you will run into problem.

The marker api has changed and you have to refactor the code in that blog post if you want to use with upgraded google maps plugin, please take a look at the answer on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55000503/9779791) that I've asked.