# Flutter: The getter 'Options' isn't defined for class 'Marker'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-flutter, fluttermap

I know flutter has changed Google_Maps_api which is causing multiple errors in my code such as

1) 'Options' isn't defined for class 'Marker'

2) Too Many Positional Arguments : 0 expected 2 found

3) 'addMarker' isn't defined for class 'GoogleMapController'

4) 'clearMarker' isn't defined for class 'GoogleMapController'

I have checked this:

[Flutter: How to add marker to Google Maps with new Marker API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000043/flutter-how-to-add-marker-to-google-maps-with-new-marker-api/55000503#55000503)

I am new to FLUTTER please help me solve these errors thanks

The Git I am using is :

https://github.com/code4func/flutter-taxiapp

```
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/model/place_item_res.dart';
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/model/step_res.dart';
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/model/trip_info_res.dart';
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/repository/place_service.dart';
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/resources/widgets/car_pickup.dart';
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/resources/widgets/home_menu.dart';
import 'package:fl_uberapp/src/resources/widgets/ride_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var _tripDistance = 0;
  final Map<String, Marker> _markers = <String, Marker>{};

  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build UI");
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
//              key: ggKey,
//              markers: Set.of(markers.values),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _mapController = controller;
              },
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(10.7915178, 106.7271422),
                zoom: 14.4746,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  AppBar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    title: Text(
                      "Taxi App",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    leading: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("click menu");
                          _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                        },
                        child: Image.asset("ic_menu.png")),
                    actions: <Widget>[Image.asset("ic_notify.png")],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 20, right: 20),
                    child: RidePicker(onPlaceSelected),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40,
              height: 248,
              child: CarPickup(_tripDistance),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: HomeMenu(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onPlaceSelected(PlaceItemRes place, bool fromAddress) {
    var mkId = fromAddress ? "from_address" : "to_address";
    _addMarker(mkId, place);
    _moveCamera();
    _checkDrawPolyline();
  }

  void _addMarker(String mkId, PlaceItemRes place) async {
    _addMarker(MarkerId, place);
    // remove old
    _markers.remove(mkId);
    _mapController.clearMarkers();

    _markers[mkId] = Marker(
        mkId,
            MarkerOptions(
            position: LatLng(place.lat, place.lng),
            infoWindowText: InfoWindowText(place.name, place.address)));

    for (var m in _markers.values) {
      await _mapController.addMarker(m.options);
    }
  }

  void _moveCamera() {
    print("move camera: ");
    print(_markers);

    if (_markers.values.length > 1) {
      var fromLatLng = _markers["from_address"].options.position;
      var toLatLng = _markers["to_address"].options.position;

      var sLat, sLng, nLat, nLng;
      if(fromLatLng.latitude <= toLatLng.latitude) {
        sLat = fromLatLng.latitude;
        nLat = toLatLng.latitude;
      } else {
        sLat = toLatLng.latitude;
        nLat = fromLatLng.latitude;
      }

      if(fromLatLng.longitude <= toLatLng.longitude) {
        sLng = fromLatLng.longitude;
        nLng = toLatLng.longitude;
      } else {
        sLng = toLatLng.longitude;
        nLng = fromLatLng.longitude;
      }

      LatLngBounds bounds = LatLngBounds(northeast: LatLng(nLat, nLng), southwest: LatLng(sLat, sLng));
      _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
    } else {
      _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(
          _markers.values.elementAt(0).options.position));
    }
  }

  void _checkDrawPolyline() {
//  remove old polyline
    _mapController.clearPolylines();

    if (_markers.length > 1) {
      var from = _markers["from_address"].options.position;
      var to = _markers["to_address"].options.position;
      PlaceService.getStep(
              from.latitude, from.longitude, to.latitude, to.longitude)
          .then((vl) {
            TripInfoRes infoRes = vl;

            _tripDistance = infoRes.distance;
            setState(() {
            });
        List<StepsRes> rs = infoRes.steps;
        List<LatLng> paths = new List();
        for (var t in rs) {
          paths
              .add(LatLng(t.startLocation.latitude, t.startLocation.longitude));
          paths.add(LatLng(t.endLocation.latitude, t.endLocation.longitude));
        }

//        print(paths);
        _mapController.addPolyline(PolylineOptions(
            points: paths, color: Color(0xFF3ADF00).value, width: 10));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through the errors that you've received, it seems that you're trying to call non-existent functions from the Objects that you're using.

`'Options' isn't defined for class 'Marker'` - checking [Marker](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Marker-class.html) class from the docs, there's no `options` that you can call.

i.e.

```
_markers.values.elementAt(0).options.position
var from = _markers["from_address"].options.position;
var to = _markers["to_address"].options.position;
```

`Too Many Positional Arguments : 0 expected 2 found` - this error was thrown because there's two arguments that you're trying to use on the method that doesn't expect to receive an argument. Check which line this error was thrown.

As for the last two, [GoogleMapController](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMapController-class.html) doesn't have `addMarker()` and `clearMarker()`.

To add markers on GoogleMapController, you need to define `markers` on GoogleMap widget.

```dart
GoogleMap(
  markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
  ...
)
```

Other than that, the rest of the code seems fine.