# Show pins of a subcollection of firebase on map - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, maps, google-maps-markers

I have an application that reads parkings data from firebase and shows some pins of on map. Now the application shows just the pins for parkings but I also want to add on the map the pins from every single parking lot saved in the "lots" subcollection of the Parkings collection.  How can I do that?

maps.dart:

```
class StoreMap extends StatelessWidget {
  StoreMap({
    Key key,
    @required this.documents,
    @required this.initialPosition,
  }) : super(key: key);

  
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;
  final LatLng initialPosition;
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition _initialPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(45.791789, 24.150390),
    zoom: 16,
  );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        markers:documents.map((document) => new Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId(document.get('name')),
                  position: LatLng(
                    document.get('location').latitude,
                    document.get('location').longitude,
                  ),
                  onTap: () => _changeMap(LatLng(
                    document.get('location').latitude,
                    document.get('location').longitude,
                  )),
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: document.get('name'),
                      snippet: document.get('numberOfLots')),
             icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueViolet)),
                )
            .toSet()
      ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _currentLocation,
        child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[400],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: document.collection("lots").get('location').latitude doesn't work because you didn't specify any documents after collection("lots")

Comment: Writing    document.collection("lots").document("h6nU1Gyx4Tlb5rpGYi5e").get('location').latitude doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `document.collection("lots").document("DocumentId").get('location').latitude` is not working is because you shouldn't pass the field name to get method. also in your code, document is just a document snapshot so what you want to do is get that document's id, and then access its sub collection and sub documents.

What you can do is something like this:

```
//The code below gets the document ids of the parking collection
//gets access the sub collection "lots" and gets all the documents inside it.
//and for every sub document, gets the data and prints the latitude of the location field
for (DocumentSnapshot document in documents){
    String documentId = document.documentId;
    DocumentReference parkingDocReference = 
    Firestore.instance.collection("Parkings").document(documentId);
    parkingDocReference.collection("lots")
    .get((QuerySnapshot subDocuments){
    List<DocumentSnapshot> subDocumentsSnapshots = subDocuments.documents;
    for (DocumentSnapshot subDoc in subDocumentsSnapshots){
         String subDocId = subDoc.documentId;
         parkingDocReference.collection("lots")
         .document(subDocId).get().then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot){ 
             print(snapshot.data["location"].latitude); //prints the latitude;
         }
  
     }
  });

}
```

get() will return `Future<DocumentSnapshot>` and that's why we are using .then() after get() so that the function will only run when the data is retrieved

**Update:**
In order to see the markers on the map, we put the code above in a function which returns `Future<List<Marker>>`. when the result is returned, you can call setState and use the updated list in your widget tree.

It's better to use [async/await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) instead of `then` as it forces the program to get the result from the future first.

```
Future<List<Marker>> _createMarkersForLotsAndParkings() async{
   List<Marker> markersList = [];
   int markerId = 0;
   for (DocumentSnapshot document in widget.documents){
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    String documentId = document.documentID;
    DocumentReference parkingDocReference = 
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Firestore.instance.collection("Parkings").document(documentId);
    DocumentSnapshot parkingDocRef = await parkingDocReference.get();
    markersList.add(Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId(markerId.toString()),
                  position: LatLng(parkingDocRef.get('location').latitude,
                      parkingDocRef.get('location').longitude),
                  onTap: () => _changeMap(LatLng(
                      parkingDocRef.get('location').latitude,
                      parkingDocRef.get('location').longitude)),
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: document.get('name'),
                      snippet: document.get('numberOfLots')),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow)),
            );
            markerId++;
    QuerySnapshot subDocuments = await parkingDocReference.collection("lots").get();
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    List<DocumentSnapshot> subDocumentsSnapshots = subDocuments.documents;
    for (DocumentSnapshot subDoc in subDocumentsSnapshots){
         // ignore: deprecated_member_use
         String subDocId = subDoc.documentID;
         DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await parkingDocReference.collection("lots")
         // ignore: deprecated_member_use
         .document(subDocId).get();
            print(snapshot.get('location').latitude);

            markersList.add(
              Marker(
                  markerId:MarkerId(markerId.toString()),
                  position: LatLng(snapshot.get('location').latitude,
                      snapshot.get('location').longitude),
                  onTap: () => _changeMap(LatLng(
                      snapshot.get('location').latitude,
                      snapshot.get('location').longitude)),
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: document.get('name'),
                      snippet: document.get('numberOfLots')),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueViolet)),
            );
            markerId++;

     }

}
return Future.value(markersList);

}
```

We call this function in `initState()`. You need to convert `StoreMap` to a `StatefullWidget` in order to be able to call `setState` and use `initState`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createMarkersForLots().then((List<Marker> lotsMarkers){
    setState((){
    markers = lotsMarkers; //rebuilds the screen with the lotsMarkers. make sure to use the markers in your widget tree to see the markers
  });
    
});
}
```

And your full code has to look something like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

class StoreMap extends StatefulWidget {
  StoreMap({
    Key key,
    @required this.documents,
    @required this.initialPosition,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;
  final LatLng initialPosition;
  static final CameraPosition _initialPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(45.791789, 24.150390),
    zoom: 16,
  );


  @override
  _StoreMapState createState() => _StoreMapState();
}

class _StoreMapState extends State<StoreMap> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();


List<Marker> markers = [];
Future<List<Marker>> _createMarkersForLotsAndParkings() async{
   List<Marker> markersList = [];
   int markerId = 0;
   for (DocumentSnapshot document in widget.documents){
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    String documentId = document.documentID;
    DocumentReference parkingDocReference = 
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    Firestore.instance.collection("Parkings").document(documentId);
    DocumentSnapshot parkingDocRef = await parkingDocReference.get();
    markersList.add(Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId(markerId.toString()),
                  position: LatLng(parkingDocRef.get('location').latitude,
                      parkingDocRef.get('location').longitude),
                  onTap: () => _changeMap(LatLng(
                      parkingDocRef.get('location').latitude,
                      parkingDocRef.get('location').longitude)),
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: document.get('name'),
                      snippet: document.get('numberOfLots')),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow)),
            );
            markerId++;
    QuerySnapshot subDocuments = await parkingDocReference.collection("lots").get();
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    List<DocumentSnapshot> subDocumentsSnapshots = subDocuments.documents;
    for (DocumentSnapshot subDoc in subDocumentsSnapshots){
         // ignore: deprecated_member_use
         String subDocId = subDoc.documentID;
         DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await parkingDocReference.collection("lots")
         // ignore: deprecated_member_use
         .document(subDocId).get();
            print(snapshot.get('location').latitude);

            markersList.add(
              Marker(
                  markerId:MarkerId(markerId.toString()),
                  position: LatLng(snapshot.get('location').latitude,
                      snapshot.get('location').longitude),
                  onTap: () => _changeMap(LatLng(
                      snapshot.get('location').latitude,
                      snapshot.get('location').longitude)),
                  infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: document.get('name'),
                      snippet: document.get('numberOfLots')),
                  icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueViolet)),
            );
            markerId++;
  
     }

}
return Future.value(markersList);

}

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createMarkersForLotsAndParkings().then((List<Marker> lotsMarkers){
    setState((){
    markers = lotsMarkers; 
  });
    
});
}


  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: StoreMap._initialPosition,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        markers: markers.toSet(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _currentLocation,
        child: Icon(Icons.location_searching),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[400],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _currentLocation() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    LocationData currentLocation;
    var location = new Location();
    try {
      currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
    } on Exception {
      currentLocation = null;
    }

    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
        zoom: 18.0,
      ),
    ));
  }

  _changeMap(LatLng position) async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;

    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
        zoom: 19.4,
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Google map shows one marker for the markers with the same Id so that's why we are using `markerId` to give each marker an unique id and see all the markers.

Comment: I get the this error: The method 'collection' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'collection'."

Comment: have a look at my updated solution and check if it works

Comment: I added that into a function. And I can see the latitude on my console but I don't know how to connect it to the LatLong(...) in markers in order to display them on the UI.

Comment: you can get the coordinates with this code. You can also create a function with the same code but it has to return a list of markers so you need to create the markers in the function. then use that list and create the markers in your widget tree. you can call the function in initState and call setState when you have the markers list

Comment: I tried this ( please see the last piece of cod I added) but the markers won't appear.

Comment: have a look at my updated answer and see if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and help. They still dont show up. Please see my last update. No error in debug console.

Comment: I think I didn't called the markers right in the widget tree

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000043/flutter-how-to-add-marker-to-google-maps-with-new-marker-api

Comment: I tried with markers:Set<Marker>.of(markers) . Still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220993/discussion-between-andreeapurta-and-morez).