# Add markers to Google maps Flutter using latitude and longitude from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

For my Flutter app, I'm trying to add markers to the google maps. However the marker didn't show up on the map. I've already stored the latitude and longitude in Firestore. Both latitude and longitude are the type number on Firestore. I didn't store them in geopoint.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPGEY.png) is the screenshot of my Firestore database.

This is my code to get the data for the marker from Firestore :

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  getMarkerData() {
    users
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('family')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        initMarker(doc['latitude'], doc['longitude'], doc['name']);
      });
    });
  }
```

So this is the code to assign the latitude and longitude data to the marker:

```
  void initMarker(lat, long, name) async {
    LatLng latlng = LatLng(lat, long);
    var markerIdVal = name;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: latlng,
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to get the data for the marker from Firestore? You may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000043/flutter-how-to-add-marker-to-google-maps-with-new-marker-api

Comment: So, I finally change my location datatype to GeoPoint on Firestore instead of using separate latitude and longitude and store it as number. I've also changed a bit of my code and now the markers are finally showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've solved the problem.

The way I solved my problems are :

1. I store my location data in GeoPoint first.

```
  //Get user location and update it in Firestore
  Future<void> updateUserLocation(LocationData newLocalData) {
    return users
        .doc(uid)
        .update({
          'location': GeoPoint(newLocalData.latitude, newLocalData.longitude),
        })
        .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
  }
```

2. In this case, I retrieved the location data from a sub collection in Firestore. You can get it from any collection you want based on your project.

```
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  getMarkerData() {
    users
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('family')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        initMarker(doc.data(), doc.id);
      });
    });
  }
```

3. Initialize the markers

```
void initMarker(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position:
          LatLng(specify['location'].latitude, specify['location'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: specify['name']),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
      //print(markerId);
    });
  }
```

4. Display the markers on maps

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        //markers: getMarkerData(), the markers didn't show up if i use this, so i use the above instead
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition: initialLocation,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          controller = controller;
        },
      ),
    );
```