# Flutter: Firebase realtime updates for Google Maps API in a Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am working on a Google map based flutter app. **What should happen in this app is, when a user adds a marker to the map it should real-time show the marker for all the users**. In the firebase firestore, markers will be saved as marker models. So when a new model is added to the firestore collection, it should update all user maps.
I was trying to use fluter Streambuilder for that. According to [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) firebase documentation link, I can display all Documents from firebase in real-time.
I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000043/flutter-how-to-add-marker-to-google-maps-with-new-marker-api) to add markers to the map.

```
//this part is directly from firebase.flutter.dev official docs
class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
}

class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['full_name']),
              subtitle: Text(data['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

According to the following code I tried to use that logic to capture the data and update it in a set I defined already. According to the following code, if that data is captured, the print statement should give a console message. The problem is, there are no console messages appearing. I already have a separate app made with GoogleMap, where using that we can set markers and update those markers in firebase.

```
   Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('markers').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Text("Loading");
          }

          snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            print(document.toString());
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            MarkerModel model = MarkerModel(
                markerId: document.id,
                latitude: data['latitude'],
                longitude: data['longitude'],
                infoTitle: data['title'],
                infoSnippet: data['snippet']);
            Provider.of<MapScreenProvider>(context).addMarkerToSet(model);
          });

          return Consumer<MapScreenProvider>(
            builder: (context, value, child) {
              return GoogleMap(
                markers: value.getMarkerSet,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                onTap: (val) {
                  print(value.getMarkerSet.toString());
                },
                // onLongPress: (userPosition) async =>await saveMarker(userPosition, context),
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) =>
                    _controller.complete(controller),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Adding markers to the map, those markers uploading in the map is fine. The issue is that using that streambuilder to get real-time docs is not working. I am using streambuilder because that is provided in the docs. if there are any other ways to get real-time updates for a google maps API, which can be used in this scenario pls suggest those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.forEach](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) and not [.map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html).

```dart
snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  print(document.toString());
  Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
  MarkerModel model = MarkerModel(
    markerId: document.id,
    latitude: data['latitude'],
    longitude: data['longitude'],
    infoTitle: data['title'],
    infoSnippet: data['snippet']);
  Provider.of<MapScreenProvider>(context).addMarkerToSet(model);
});
```