# how to update location on map using geolocator in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I would like to change the location of the blue mark on Google Maps to another location when a new address is selected. I have tried literally everything I could through trial and error but the mark seems to stay where it is i.e It remains at the current location. I would like to know how the current location of a user(The Blue Mark) can be updated to a new location when selected. I have used the `geolocator` package. Also do note that we are using Google Places API to display. This is for the purpose of selecting a new address from the list of suggestions that the user searches for.

Code that detects/changes the current location

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class LocationProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  LocationProvider() {}

  String _deliveryAddress = '';
  double _currentLatitude = 0.0;
  double _currentLongitude = 0.0;

  String get deliveryAddress {
    return _deliveryAddress;
  }

  double get currentLatitude {
    return _currentLatitude;
  }

  double get currentLongitude {
    return _currentLongitude;
  }

  String? postCode;
  String? addressLine;
  String? locality;
  String? city;
  String? selectedState;

  Future<Position> _getGeoLocationPosition() async {      
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  Future<void> GetAddressFromLatLong(Position position) async {
    List<Placemark> placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    print('Placemarks $placemarks');
    Placemark place = placemarks[0];
    _address = '${place.subLocality}';
    _deliveryAddress =
        '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}';
    _state = place.administrativeArea;

    postCode = place.postalCode!;
    addressLine = '${place.street} ${place.thoroughfare}';
    locality = place.subLocality!;
    city = place.locality!;
    selectedState = place.administrativeArea!;

    print('Initial Address $postCode');
    print('Initial Address $addressLine');
    print('Initial Address $locality');
    print('Initial Address $city');
    print('Initial Address $selectedState');

    _coorDinates['lat'] = position.latitude;
    _coorDinates['lng'] = position.longitude;
    print('Delivery Address: $_deliveryAddress');
    print('Coordinates in Location ${_coorDinates['lat']}');
    print('Coordinates in Location ${_coorDinates['lng']}');
    // setState(() {});
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> newAddress(double latitude, double longitude) async {   //This is where a new address is selected from
    List<Placemark> placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
    print(placemarks);
    Placemark place = placemarks[0];
    _deliveryAddress =
        '${place.street}, ${place.thoroughfare} ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.administrativeArea} ${place.country}';
    postCode = place.postalCode!;
    addressLine = '${place.street} ${place.thoroughfare}';
    locality = place.subLocality!;
    city = place.locality!;
    selectedState = place.administrativeArea!;
    print('Initial Address $postCode');
    print('Initial Address $addressLine');
    print('Initial Address $locality');
    print('Initial Address $city');
    print('Initial Address $selectedState');
    print('New Address $_deliveryAddress');
    // setState(() {});
    _state = place.administrativeArea;
    _coorDinates['lat'] = latitude;
    _coorDinates['lng'] = longitude;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> getLocation() async {
    Position position = await _getGeoLocationPosition();
    print('Current Location Response: $position');
    print('Current LatitudeSSSSSSSSS: ${position.latitude}');
    print('Current LongitudeSSSSSSSSSS:${position.longitude}');
    GetAddressFromLatLong(position).then((_) {
      if (_address.length > 0) {
        isLoading = false;
      } else {
        isLoading = true;
      }
    });

    _currentLatitude = position.latitude;
    _currentLongitude = position.longitude;

    notifyListeners();
    // return position;
  }
}
```

This is the widget that is meant for displaying and selecting results from the Google Places API:

```
class SelectAddressState extends State<SelectAddress> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  List<dynamic> _placesList = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> _placesId = {};
  bool isLoading = true;
  double latitude = 0.0;
  double longitude = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    inputQueryText;
    setPlaceId;
    super.initState();
  }

  void inputQueryText(String value) {
    Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .findPlaceAutoCompleteSearch(value)
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _placesList =
            Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false).places;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> setPlaceId(String placeId) async {
    _placesId =
        await Provider.of<ChangeLocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .getLatLong(placeId);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      latitude = _placesId['result']['geometry']['location']['lat'];
      longitude = _placesId['result']['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    });

    print('Latitude $latitude');
    print('Longitude $longitude');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ......
        ......
        ......
        title: Row(
          children: [
            InkWell(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white)),
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  .....
                  .....
                  .....
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                          flex: 9,
                          fit: FlexFit.tight,
                          child: Center(
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: _controller,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                inputQueryText(value);
                              },
                              .......
                              .......
                              .......
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: height * 1,
        // color: Colors.red,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              setPlaceId(_placesList[index]['place_id']).then((_) {
                print('Here Goes The Lat: $latitude');
                print('Here Goes The Lng: $longitude');
                Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .newAddress(latitude, longitude)   //This is where we select a new address from the list
                    .then((_) {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();  //The idea here was to select a new address and then go back to the Map Widget.
                });
                // });
              });
            },
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.02, right: width * 0.02),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: height * 0.08,
              // color: Colors.amber,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(Icons.my_location, color: Colors.green),
                  SizedBox(width: width * 0.02),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      _placesList[index]['description'],
                      // overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                      textScaleFactor: textScale,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          itemCount: _placesList.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Map Widget:
Things look fine initially. But then upon selecting a new location, the blue mark remains at the same spot i.e my current location.

```
class _MapWidgetState extends State<MapWidget> {
  late ClusterManager _manager;
  double currentMapLatitude = 0.0;
  double currentMapLongitude = 0.0;

  LatLng? latLng;
  CameraPosition? cameraPosition;
  bool isLoading = true;

  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  GoogleMapController? newGoogleMapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _manager = _initClusterManager();
    Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getLocation()
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    currentMapLatitude =
        Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).currentLatitude;
    currentMapLongitude =
        Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false).currentLongitude;
    latLng = LatLng(currentMapLatitude, currentMapLongitude);
    cameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: latLng!, zoom: 18.0);

    super.initState();
  }

  locateUserPosition() async {     //This method seems to retain the current co-ordinates. Is there anyway this can be updated?
    Position currentPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    LatLng latLngPosition =
        LatLng(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);

    print('Current Position Latitude: ${currentPosition.latitude}');
    print('Current Position Longitude: ${currentPosition.longitude}');

    CameraPosition newCameraPosition =
        CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition, zoom: 18.0);

    newGoogleMapController!
        .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(newCameraPosition));
  }

  ClusterManager _initClusterManager() {
    return ClusterManager<Place>(items, _updateMarkers,
        markerBuilder: _markerBuilder);
  }

  void _updateMarkers(Set<Marker> markers) {
    print('Updated ${markers.length} markers');
    setState(() {
      this.markers = markers;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return isLoading
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Color(0xff00ffba),
            ),
          )
        : Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: mediaQuery.height * 0.6,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition!,
                  markers: markers,
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                    _manager.setMapId(controller.mapId);
                    newGoogleMapController = controller;
                    locateUserPosition();
              Positioned(
                //top: 2,
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(right: 55.0, left: 55.0, top: 30.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      hintText: 'Destination',
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.location_on,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }

  Future<Marker> Function(Cluster<Place>) get _markerBuilder =>
      (cluster) async {
        return Marker(
          .....
          .....
          .....
        );
      };

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getMarkerBitmap(int size, {String? text}) async {
    ..........
    .........
  }
}
```

Here are screenshots for the same:

This is the screenshot from when the app starts initially. You can see that it takes the current location and also marks it on the map
[image]

This is the screen where Places API returns results:
[image]

In the next image, you can see that although the address gets updated at the top, the map marker remains at the same point:
[image]

Comment: The blue marker is your current location, you can't change it by selecting another location. Why not add another marker for the selected location? And let the blue marker show your actual location. Or you can disable it `myLocationEnabled: false`, and use your own marker for your current location then you can move it to the selected location.

Answer (score 0):

Blue mark is for your current location you can' change that but what you need is marker so you can achieve that using your marker.

Change your marker position to your selected Latitude Longitude.

If you still don't find any solution then [Flutter: How to add marker to Google Maps with new Marker API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000043/flutter-how-to-add-marker-to-google-maps-with-new-marker-api) visit this link for how to add marker in **GoogleMap Flutter**.